# Left continuous of a CDF.

Tags: probability

I am working through Oksendal SDEs book and have a question about an exercise (number 2.2):

$X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a r.v with $F(x)= \mathbb{P}[X \leq x]$.

We can show $F$ is increasing and right-continuous as the question asked.

On the other hand, is F left continuous?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: No. Consider some distributions with positive probability on points.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: You can say F has left limits and so is [càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) as a French abbreviation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ is not in general left-continuous. In fact we always have $P(X=a)=F(a)-F(a-)$ where the minus means limit from the left. So if there are any $a$ for which $P(a)>0$ then $F$ is not left continuous at those $a$. This happens for a discrete distribution, and for some others often called "mixed" which are partly continuous and have some specific points with nonzero probability.